# Using Native Android x86-64 shared libs on non-Android Linux

Tags: android, reverse-engineering

An APK I decompiled has Java that makes calls to C++ functions located in Android "native" shared libraries. These .so libs are compiled for both ARM and x86-64. I'd like to call some of the functions within these shared libraries from my own non-Android C++ programs but I get various linking errors at compile time like:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: liblog.so, needed by ./libBridge.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libandroid.so, needed by ./libBridge.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libc.so, needed by ./libBridge.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
./libBridge.so: undefined reference to `realloc@LIBC'
```

I do not know too much about Android but I suppose this has to do with incompatible C / C++ libraries between Android and non-Android Linux.

How would I go about compiling and linking successfully with these required libraries so that I may call the desired functions within?

Comment: Have you tried to extract the files mentioned from your Android device? But be aware that if those Android specific libraries are called within the method you want to use the call will most likely fail as your runtime environment misses the Android specific services like logcat.